# Interrupting a long MacPorts installation

Tags: macos, qt4, terminal, macports

I'm currently installing [qt4-mac](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=qt4-mac) and it's taking forever to build. I've searched around and I've discovered that it's going to take anywhere from 2-5 hours to install.

Is there a way to interrupt this installation process and if so do I need to do some clean-up afterwards?

Comment: just curious... why you won't download Qt from official site?

Comment: Arr 'cause I'm lazy and prefer to have MacPorts manage all my dependencies for me. I've started getting into building things from the source - but yeah, I've still got lots to learn. The command line is a little scary for artists like me, but it gets easier the more you use it. :)

Comment: Qt package has its all dependencies inside... MacPorts is indeed cool, but homebrew works (in my opinion) better. Also It's cool if you realy need some unavailable on Mac Linux tools... otherwise I'd not encourage to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `control+c`?

Also, I'm not entirely sure about cleanup, but according to the [MacPorts docs](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html), the command `sudo port -fp uninstall --follow-dependents [your port name here]` should help (this page is about uninstalling MacPorts itself, but it's the same command). I'm not sure how MacPorts treats interrupted installations and if it treats "half-installed" items as uninstallable, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Yeah, I just found the `ctrl+c` thing online, but thank you! I also did `sudo port clean qt4-mac` before I ran the uninstall command which cleared up a few gigabytes of disk space, but I'm not sure if that's necessary if you're uninstalling.

Comment: According to two of answers, the suggestion `ctrl+c` can cause some serious problems. Please take these answers into consideration before proceeding with `ctrl+c`.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old thread, but I'd like to share my personal opinion on this.

Once upon a time (two years ago I guess, not sure about the current state of affairs) I interrupted a MacPorts update (`sudo port upgrade outdated`) with not `Ctrl+C` (roughly `SIGINT`), but rather `SIGKILL`, since I was running into some trouble with the hardware at that time. I ended up with a **completely broken** install that defied all efforts of clean-up or recovery, and I ended up restoring a full backup of `/opt/local`.

I never dare to interrupt MacPorts install/upgrade since then, even with `Ctrl+C`'s.

The moral of the story is: interrupting MacPorts installation process could be potentially pretty dangerous. Leave it alone if it is simply running for a long time (sometimes building *does* take forever). If you do believe it is hanging rather than actually building, make sure you have a backup, and proceed with caution (of course, it's too late to back up when you are already running the install).

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me although I actually used `Ctrl+C` therefore I totally agree with you about not doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I also would like to chime in. I think a good practice is to watch where you are in the installation before `Ctrl+C`ing, then clean the dependency you were on and redo the main install later. For example, I was installing kdenlive and killed it in the middle of the virtuoso (one of many dependencies) install. Later, I did a `sudo port -v selfupdate`, then a `port clean virtuoso`, then started the kdenlive install again with `sudo port install kdenlive`. This seems to be a decent way to go; it cruised through the first part and picked up at normal speed when it got to virtuoso.

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't press Ctrl+C

Building on the answer by 4ae1e1, while (s)he interrupted the process sending a `SIGKILL` signal, I interrupted it sending an actual `SIGINT` signal, i.e. the usual `Ctrl+C`, and now no MacPorts app are working so far.

So I completely agree with 4ae1e1.

#### If you need your machine

If you need to suspend the installation, e.g. because you need your CPU to be available for other things, to send a `SIGSTOP` signal instead, in order to *pause* the installation.

```
kill -STOP installationPIDs
```

Once you are ready to resume it, you can send a `SIGCONT` signal and you can complete it.

```
kill -CONT installationPIDs
```

You should easily find the PIDs of the installation process, for example you can just run `htop` and look among the processes using most of the CPU.

#### If you change your mind about an installation

Even if you change your mind and you do not want that port/package installed anymore, I strongly recommend to just complete the installation (pausing it when needed as suggested below) and just uninstall the port/package afterwards. It sounds like a waste of time, but it is the safest thing to do.